# Average of rows where column = A within distinct rows on another column grouped by a third column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I'm trying to query a kind of averaged count from a table I didn't design, where basically I want a list, grouped by one column, with the number of distinct values of another column matching a given criterion, and *of those*, the number of rows matching another criterion (which I'll use to created the averaged count or whatever it is). This can't be hard, but I'm having a bad set theory day and any pointers will be gratefully received.

Here's the simplified and genericized scenario (schema and sample data below). Say we have three columns:

- `objid` *(has a clustered index)*
- `userid` *(no index, I might be able to add one)*
- `actiontype` *(no index, I might be able to add one)*

None of these is unique, and none can be `null`. We want to completely ignore any rows where `actiontype` is `none`. We want to know, per `userid`, how many `actiontype = 'flag'` rows there are on average per object that user has interacted with.

So if we have "ahmed", "joe", and "maria", and joe interacted with 3 objects and raised 5 flags, the number there is `5 / 3 = 1.6666` continuous; if "ahmed" interacted with 3 objects and didn't raise any flags, his number would be `0`; if "maria" interacted with 5 objects and raised 4 flags, her number would be `4 / 5 = 0.8`:

```
+--------+------------------+
| userid | flags_per_object |
+--------+------------------+
| ahmed  | 0                |
| joe    | 1.66666667       |
| maria  | 0.8              |
+--------+------------------+
```

I won't be remotely surprised if this is closed as a duplicate, I'm just not finding it.

Here's the simplified table setup and sample data:

```
create table tmp
(
    objid      varchar(254) not null,
    userid     varchar(254) not null,
    actiontype varchar(254) not null
)
create clustered index tmp_objid on tmp(objid)

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'none')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'none')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'update')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'close')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'joe', 'flag')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'joe', 'none')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'joe', 'none')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'joe', 'close')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'joe', 'flag')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'joe', 'none')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('delta', 'joe', 'update')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'maria', 'update')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'maria', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'maria', 'flag')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'maria', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'maria', 'flag')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'maria', 'update')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'maria', 'close')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('delta', 'maria', 'update')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('epsilon', 'maria', 'update')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('alpha', 'ahmed', 'none')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('beta', 'ahmed', 'none')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'ahmed', 'none')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('gamma', 'ahmed', 'update')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('delta', 'ahmed', 'update')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('delta', 'ahmed', 'close')

insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('epsilon', 'ahmed', 'update')
insert into tmp (objid, userid, actiontype) values ('epsilon', 'ahmed', 'close')
```

Comment: No, `3 / 5` yields `0.6`. And `1.6666…` is the result of `5 / 3`.

Comment: @Andriy: Told you I was having an off day. Thank you, fixed. It was the calculation part that was wrong, the result was right. Looking for `5 / 3`, not `3 / 5` (in "joe"'s case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **It depends.**

In my testing, my solution is the slowest of the bunch, regardless of what test data I use. With real life data, it's about half the speed of the fastest solution.

[Mikael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237144/average-of-rows-where-column-a-within-distinct-rows-on-another-column-grouped-b/6239427#6239427) is faster for the test data quoted in my question, and faster for a larger-but-still-small data set (our testing system, about 2k rows) in my real-life tables.

But [a1ex07's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237144/average-of-rows-where-column-a-within-distinct-rows-on-another-column-grouped-b/6237463#6237463) is faster for my full-size real-life tables (our live system, about 700k rows). There's not a lot of distance between a1ex07's and Mikael's, but a1ex07's definitely has the edge.

I ended up actually using Mikael's solution, though, because it's easier to conceptualize if you're not a l33t DB person (and the people doing maintenance on this code, of which the SQL is only a small part, won't be) and easier to adapt to various other scenarios.

Thus this community wiki meta-answer, which I'll accept when the time limit passes, rather than accepting either of their excellent answers. If you found this helpful, please do vote up both [Mikael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237144/average-of-rows-where-column-a-within-distinct-rows-on-another-column-grouped-b/6239427#6239427) and [a1ex07's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237144/average-of-rows-where-column-a-within-distinct-rows-on-another-column-grouped-b/6237463#6237463), as I have done.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following :

```
select  t1.userid,
CASE cnt2 
WHEN 0 THEN 0
ELSE ISNULL(cast(cnt2 as float)/cnt1,0)
END as num
FROM
(
  select userid, COUNT(distinct(t1.objid)) as cnt2
  from tmp as t1
  where t1.actiontype <> 'none'
  group by t1.userid
) t1

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT t2.userid, COUNT(*) as cnt1
FROM tmp as t2
WHERE t2.actiontype='flag'
GROUP BY t2.userid)b ON (b.userid = t1.userid)
```

Even though it looks uglier than your solution, it surprisingly generates a better execution plan based on test data you provided.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It's returning NULL for "ahmed" rather than 0, but I could work around that with a `CASE`. I'm worried that this is showing two table scans in the EP rather than one scan in my solution, though. (I'm rubbish at comparing EPs, but "table scan" jumps out at me...and makes me think I should have mentioned what indexes we can expect to have in the question.)

Comment: I've added those notes about indexes now. Basically adding that to my standalone test table (doh!) changed the table scans in the EP into clustered index scans.

Comment: Yeah, I also checked io statistics output for both versions. It showed "Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 50, Table 'tmp'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1" for yours and "Table 'tmp'. Scan count 4, logical reads 4" for mine. And I was quite surprised to see that execution plan window shows 28% and 72% percent for relative cost for mine and yours respectively. I also tested a couple of other approaches but all of them behaved a way worse than yours.

Comment: And sorry about missing point with `NULL`; I think `ISNULL(..,0)` should fix it

Comment: @a1ex07: Thanks again. I see similar relative numbers in my tests with the test table too (yours = ~30%, mine = ~70%). Curiously, with the real data and real relations, despite their being basically the same with a couple of other column value checks thrown in, it goes the other way (about yours = ~66%, mine = ~34%). Which just goes to prove that test tables can only ever be *indicative* and you always have to test with the real data, nothing against your solution at all. Thank you again for your insight, much appreciated.

Comment: @a1ex07: ...and swings back *your* way (markedly, 25%/75%) if I do a reporting table with irrelevancies removed (cutting the data size by a factor of 10) that I keep up-to-date with triggers. The target DB server spends 99.5% of its time twiddling its thumbs, so it's not going to care about the trigger overhead. Just waiting for whether there are other ideas, but I think yours is the way to go.

Comment: :) Maybe you need to try `INCLUDE` some columns to the existing indexes?

Comment: Or another explanation - original approach requires less physical scans but more logical. When the number of rows is very big, many logical reads outperform one physical...

Comment: @a1ex07: Real table has ~7m rows, so that could be it. Reporting excerpt is more like 700k rows.

Comment: 700k also seems like a quite large number. I'd try to query the real table without extra columns to see if it makes difference...

Answer (score 2):

[*(Answering my own question.)*](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

I do have something that works:

```
select   userid,
         cast(count(case when actiontype = 'flag' then 1 else null end) as float)
         /
         count(distinct(objid))
         as flags_per_object
from     tmp
where    actiontype <> 'none'
group by userid
```

....but I can't help feeling there's a better way...

Comment: That's just about the way I would do it as well (technically, I would use a sum instead of a count to count the flags, but one's as good as another).  Is there a problem with this way?  Is it slow, or is there another problem with this method that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @dpmattingly: That's kind of the question: *Is* there something wrong with it. :-) I just have this nagging feeling that there's a better way, but as I said, I'm having a bad SQL / set theory day and can't tell you *why* I have that nagging feeling.

Comment: I often drop `else null` in CASE expressions, because it is implied anyway, but that's just a matter of taste. Nothing seems to be wrong with your solution.

Comment: @Andrij: Thanks. (I have `else null` there. Or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
  select userid,
         sum(case actiontype when 'flag'
               then 1
               else 0
             end) as Flags
  from tmp
  where actiontype <> 'none'
  group by userid, [objid]
)
select userid,
       cast(sum(Flags) as float)/count(*) as flags_per_object
from cte
group by userid
```

As a sub query instead of CTE

```
select userid,
       cast(sum(Flags) as float)/count(*) as flags_per_object
from (select userid,
             sum(case actiontype when 'flag'
                   then 1
                   else 0
                 end) as Flags
      from tmp
      where actiontype <> 'none'
      group by userid, [objid]) as T
group by userid
```

Comment: Thanks, but SQL Server complains of a syntax error on the `;` (and if I remove it, on the `with`). Version issue? This client is *still* on SQL Server 2000; they're upgrading to 2008 later this year...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder – Updated answer using sub query instead. There is no difference in the query plan between the two on 2008.

Comment: Thanks again, much appreciated! With both the test data and my 700k rows of real data, this performs much better than my solution. It outperforms @a1ex07's with the test data, but @a1ex07's outperforms it with the real data. It's a close race in both cases, and I really like the simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  userid,
  flags_per_object =
    COUNT(CASE actiontype WHEN 'flag' THEN objid END) *
    1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT objid)
FROM
  tmp
WHERE actiontype <> 'none'
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: Thanks. But that seems to me to return incorrect results. I'm getting `0.66666666` for "joe" when "joe" interacts with 3 objects and raises 5 flags. 5 flags per 3 objects = `5 / 3` = `1.666667`. Similarly, "maria" interacts with 5 objects and raises 4 flags. 4 flags for 5 objedcts is `4 / 5` = `0.8`, but your query is giving me `0.4`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I see now. Then `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE…)` should be simply `COUNT(CASE…)`, but that makes my solution basically identical to yours.